# virtualenv doesn't work in mac with anaconda

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda

I have virtualenv installed and also 2 versions of python installed. One is through homebrew another is in anaconda. But virtualenv doesn't work with either of them. I found some posts saying this is due to messy python version. But even I point to different python, it still doesn't work. Is there any solution for this ? Thanks

```
jzhangMBPr:~ jzhang$ virtualenv -p /Users/jzhang/anaconda/bin/python a
Already using interpreter /Users/jzhang/anaconda/bin/python
Using base prefix '/Users/jzhang/anaconda'
New python executable in /Users/jzhang/a/bin/python
ERROR: The executable /Users/jzhang/a/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/jzhang' (should be '/Users/jzhang/a')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable

jzhangMBPr:~ jzhang$ virtualenv  a
Using base prefix '/Users/jzhang/anaconda'
New python executable in /Users/jzhang/a/bin/python
ERROR: The executable /Users/jzhang/a/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/jzhang' (should be '/Users/jzhang/a')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably pointing virtualenv to the wrong Python installation. I thought its regardless of which python interpreter you have. Virtualenv comes with a -p flag which let you specifically which interpreter in use.

Use;

```
virtualenv -p python test
```

Instead;

```
virtualenv test
```

Also you can use virtualenv -h, which appears an help documentation for usage of other specific virtualenv flags.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your conda init. For me running :

`conda init bash`

solved the problem.